# How do I warp to a safe-spot in wait mode?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

During many battles, there are safe spots you can warp to (windows, rocks, etc) to regain HP and mana.  In Active Mode, you warp to these by rotating the camera to look at them and hitting ◯

However, in Wait Mode that doesn't work.  When I look at a safe-spot and hit ◯, it still warps me to the nearest enemy.

**How can I warp to safe spots in Wait Mode?**

Comment: I'm not confident enough in this to make it an answer, but I seem to go where I want when I hold the button down, and seem to warp to an enemy if I just tap it.

Comment: I have seen this too, tapping targets enemies, holding targets safe spots.

Comment: I believe the difference depends on whether you are target locked in an enemy when you warp.

Comment: @Fogmeister: I was not holding the lock button, obviously..

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft ah ok. Just checking :-)

Comment: @Sterno is correct.  It threw me off, because there was no wait mode on the demo version of the game, and I kept warping to enemies inadvertently, as well.  The way it worked in active mode almost caused me to wait for the PC version, for easier targetting, but with no PC confirmation, I chose not to wait. =D

Comment: On tapping vs. holding - the on-screen button guide will show an orange triangle over a button if you are meant to hold it, and it will show the button glyph only if it's meant to be tapped.

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way I've found so far, is to point the camera towards a Warp Point, so you can see the point, and the button prompt and then hold down the warp button.